# Use Style in TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm new to this and can't quit get the correct syntax. This works correctly to capture the `Left Mouse click` on the textbox within the treeview:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                DataType="{x:Type r:NetworkViewModel}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
                >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NetworkIP}" Width="110" >
                             <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                             </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        </TextBlock>

                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

How can this be done using a `Style` block in the `Resources`? 
The goal being to use the same style for all `TextBoxes` in the `TreeView`. Something that would sit in the `Usercontrol.Resources` and be refrenced by the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could define a template in the controls or windows resources with a target type (opposed to key `x:Key=...`) to have it automatically applied to all items in the tree view.

Here is a small example with a definition of a template in the window resources, which contains the `InputBindings` definition. This template will be automatically applied to all objects of type `ItemViewModel` if no other template is explicitly defined by the `ItemsControl` or `TreeView`. In this example, the items are displayed in a simple `ItemsControl` but it works for the `TreeView` just the same.

Note that for this to work, all items in the `TreeView` need to be of the same type. *It is not sufficient if they are derived from the same base type. The template will only be applied, if the type defined in `Template.DataType` is exactly the same as the type of the ViewModel*. If your TreeViews `ItemsScource`s contain mixed type, you would need to specify the template for every type separately.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:ItemViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="110" >
                <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding 
                        MouseAction="LeftClick"
                        Command="{Binding SelectItem}" />
                </TextBlock.InputBindings>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks! Too bad I can't use a base type or interface in XAML, it would make like simplier. Thanks again for all the gread help!

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe you can consider using one ViewModel type for several model types which are all derived from one base class. Depends on the case but maybe worth considering. Cheers and good luck!